# Sharepoint Server: Step by step guide to moving data to sql server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, migration

I have a sharepoint server used for multiple clients which I installed on my internal server with default settings. Now I want to move this to a website host instead.

I need to transfer all this data from the integrated SP server to a SQL server, but I can't find a step by step guide to achieve this. I don't even know where the data is currently stored (I assume in the local filesystem where sharepoint is current running) how to export and then reimport and then tie this to the new Sharpoint site once it's on the new hosting environment.

Does anyone have a step by step guide on how to achieve this? I can't seem to find a solution that works by using google.

Thanks in advance

Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a starting point:

1. Ask your hosting provider what format(s) they support.

And then work from there...

More helpfully, take a look at using the [Backup-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx) cmdlet rather than thinking at the SQL level. You can back up a single site/web and then use [Restore-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx) to put it somewhere else.